# Type constraint in a Discriminated Union

Tags: f#

Consider that

```
type Foo =
  | I of int
  | S of string



let test = [ I(5); I(9); I(7)]
```

It works, but now I want 'test' to be of type Foo too and still be a list of either I or S. E.g.

```
let test = L( [ I(5); I(9); I(42) ] ) //works!
let test2 = L( [ I(5); I(9); S("stuff") ] ) //type error
let test3 = L( [ I(5); I(9); L([]) ] ) //type error
```

I try that..

```
type Foo =
  | I of int
  | S of string
  | L of 'T list when 'T :> Foo
```

I know it obviously doesn't work. It was just something natural for me to write.

Thanks a lot for helping!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I and S are really interesting in and of themselves, i.e. you want to know I lists from S lists, then why not be explicit?

```
type I = int
type S = string

type Foo =
    | I
    | S
    | LI of I list
    | LS of S list
```

Comment: Yes and actually it's  what I have done. Thanks for pointing this out! But the question was more about if yes or no F# type system could handle it.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use a generic type constraint for 'discriminated union'. But you can pin down the specific type to that Discriminated union, like the following.

```
type Foo = 
    | I of int 
    | S of string
    | L of Foo list


// Usage
let test = L( [ I(5); I(9); S("stuff"); L([]); I(42) ] )
```

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

Chris has a good answer.  If it's the case that you don't want lists to nest, you could also do

```
type FooAtom = 
    | I of int 
    | S of string

type Foo = 
    | A of FooAtom
    | L of FooAtom list

let test  = L( [ I(5); I(9); S("stuff"); I(42) ] )
let test2 = A( I(5) )
```

Comment: Good call! I agree that doing it my way enables you to bleed sub lists into the main list - while defining a second discriminated union avoids that mess.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Brian! In fact it's not exactly what I want to do. I'm looking for a way to constraint elements of the list to only be from a particular type like in my example.

Comment: Then Brians solution will work for you. It wont allow Foo to have L([L([I(42)])]).

Comment: No, because I want that FooAtom have all the same subtype, [A(I(5)); A(S("S"))] shouldn't compile. Everything should be I, or everything S, but not a mix.

Answer (score 1):

You may not say "that's list of some Foo's members and other (not Foo) things" in terms of the F# type system.
But you can use runtime and yet another level of indirection:

```
type Foo = I of int | S of string

let (|F|L|) (o: obj) =
  match o with
  | :? Foo as v -> F v
  | :? list<Foo> as v -> L v
  | _ -> failwith "unknown type"
;;

let f = function
  | F _ -> "Foo"
  | L _ -> "List of Foos"
;;

List.map f [ box (I 1); box (S "stuff"); box ([I 2; S "foo"]) ]
```

Comment: You really shouldn't do it that way :-/ 

The dynamic type tests (:?) incur a pretty big performance hit and since you are boxing the items you are losing type safety - so you can hit that 'failwith' case at runtime and not get any support from the F# compiler.